# PHP and AJAX FormData not communicating

Tags: php, ajax

This is driving me crazy! I can't understand why ajax doesn't send the file to php, is there anyone able to understand? Here's the code:

----- HTML -----

```
 <input id="mmSelectedDoc" name="selectedFiles[]" type="file" multiple></input>
```

----- JS-----

```
    mmSingFile = (document.getElementById("mmSelectedDoc").files)[0];

    var mmFilesData = new FormData();

    mmFilesData.append("selectedFiles[]", mmSingFile, encodeURIComponent(mmSingFile.name));

    var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.onreadystatechange = function(e){
        if (x.readyState==4 && x.status==200){
           console.log(x.responseText);
        }
    }
    log(mmFilesData.get("selectedFiles[]"));
    x.open("POST","uploader.php", true);
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
    x.send(mmFilesData);
```

----- PHP -----

```
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_FILES);
die();
```

when i log mmFilesData.get(...) before sending, I can see there's a file inside, but as log on onreadystatechange=4 There are only empty arrays. If I change the content-type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded i get from the post var_dump a result like this:

```
  ["-----------------------------172450022319283172571100694258

Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=>
  string(813) ""selectedFiles[]"; filename="10434360_995996657086820_5574771356675124169_n.jpg"

Content-Type: image/jpeg

��here's in ascii the file content��
```

What's happening??? Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Don't set a content type on your xhr object when sending a formdata object.
Don't uri encode the filename in the append function.